# How to target nested fields in a Firestore security rule

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

My app has the unfortunate design that user settings are nested under "settings" in the user object. I now find myself in a situation where I want to allow the app to only update a specific field in the settings. So I've attempted to write a rule like this:

```
match /users/{userId} {
      allow get: if userMatchesId(userId)
      allow update:
        if userMatchesId(userId)
        && request.resource.data.keys().hasOnly(['settings.someSetting'])
        && request.resource.data.settings.someSetting is list;
}
```

This syntax for field paths does not seem to be supported, and [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/security/rules-fields) has no mention of this either. Is there a way?

If not, I will reconsider moving settings to its own collection, but it involves some refactoring of course...

Answer (score 1):

The `keys()` method returns direct keys only and not the nested ones. If you want to get affected keys within `settings` map then try the following:

```
match /users/{userId} {
      allow get: if userMatchesId(userId)
      allow update:
        if userMatchesId(userId)
        && request.resource.data.settings.keys().hasOnly(['someSetting'])
        && request.resource.data.settings.someSetting is list;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work for me. I am updating the document using a field path, because I need the other properties in the map to remain untouched: ```updateDoc(doc(db, `users/${userId}`), { 'settings.someSetting': newValue })```.

Comment: @ThijsKoerselman the rules are working for me. Can you try log `newValue` and check if it is an array? Make sure you are replacing all the values correctly as the example in your questions seems to have some dummy fields names and so.

Comment: Without the keys() rule it is working for me, so I think the problem is not with the list, but I'll try to investigate.

In the meantime I also tried using setDoc instead of updateDoc: ```setDoc(doc(db, `users/${userId}`),{ settings: { someSetting: newValue } },{ mergeFields: ['settings.someSetting'] }```

It's time for me to start writing unit tests on my rules ;)

Comment: @ThijsKoerselman maybe try hardcoding the update body once, I tried with `updateDoc(doc(db, \`users/${userId}\`), { 'settings.someSetting': ["test"] })` and this worked perfectly. The rules are exactly the same in my answer above. f

Comment: Odd. I've now tried it with the exact rule you posted and the hardcoded call. But still it gives me a permissions error. I'm not testing this with an emulator. I'll get back to it later since my time is up for now...